# Cin Execution Not Working (program.exe < filewithdata.txt)

Tags: c++, executable, cin

```
    int main()
{
    string file;
    cin >> file;
    ifstream f(file.c_str());
```

I am wanting to make my program work/run by running the command: project.exe < filewithdata.txt

What am I doing wrong folks? Thanks.

Comment: `<` pipes the *contents* of the file on stdin, not its name. Is that what you want?

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes that is what I want. I need help converting the lines to integers (each line has 4 integers).

Comment: Then you should read the lines of integers from `std::cin`, not a filename, exactly like you would if you typed them interactively by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     int main()
     {
        string line;
        int x,y,x2,y2;
        while (getline(cin, line))
        {
            stringstream s (line.c_str());
            s>>x>>y>>x2>>y2;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Let me know if that helped you out man.

Answer (score 0):

As was correctly pointed out in a comment a few minutes ago, the < redirects standard input to be the contents of the file.  So, if you want to read in and process the data in the file named filewithdata.txt, you don't have to worry about the file name in your C++ code.  You just read the data from the standard input (cin object in C++).

Please let me know if you run into further difficulties.